# Why are my angular curly braces not working?

Tags: angularjs, controller, curly-braces

My curly braces are showing up as curly braces, I don't get what's wrong, I did everything...when I use the controller to manipulate the input box, it works. But when I sumbit text into the input box on my browser, it doesn't do anything..

This is where I create my module:

```
'use strict';
 var foodApp=angular.module('foodApp', []);
```

This is my html:

```
<script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Food App</title>
</head>

<body>
<div  ng-controller="foodController" ng-app="foodApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foods"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Healthy Lunch?" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <h4>{{outcome}}</h4>

        {{foods}}
</div>
<script src="/js/food.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/foodController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller page:

```
foodApp.controller('foodController', function($scope)
{

var foods = $scope.foods;
$scope.outcome=foods;
var foodsArray=foods.split(',');

if(foodsArray.length<=4)
$scope.outcome="Bon Appetit!";

else if(foodsArray.length<=7)
$scope.outcome="Pig!";

else
 $scope.outcome="One at a time, your scale is going to shout!!";
});
```

Comment: Are you forgetting a `<script src="">` tag to include the angular framework? It seems to be missing from your example.

Comment: No, it's at the top of my html file, included like this <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: Include this for starters: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"> </script> It needs to be inside of your html tags as well. Can you look into your browser console and see what other errors are getting thrown. Can't 100% tell but it also looks like your if else block may be structured incorrectly since you need brackets.

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Are there any error messages? Could you include the code where you create your `foodApp` module? Right now, there isn't enough information to solve your problem - besides your controller code probably not working as you're expecting, but that's an entirely different issue.

Comment: No, this didn't help. There are no errors getting thrown, and the if/else block shouldn't matter because the braces are showing up when they shouldn't.

Comment: I added it. There are no errors showing up. Just the curly braces show up on the browser. However, if I do something from my controller like $scope.foods="hi", it shows up and the curly braces get replaced. If I try to manipulate from the input box to change the value in the braces or if I don't do anything at all, the curly braces are there.

Comment: So, I discovered if I comment out the part where I split the foods array, that the braces disappear. Any idea on what's wrong with having that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in fact in your controller. The code you have in your controller is only executed once, when the controller is constructed. As such the variable `foods` is undefined (since `$scope.foods` is also undefined). A couple of lines later, you try to run `foods.split(..)` but since it's undefined, it throws an exception and the application fails. This is shown as an error in the developer console of your browser.

To fix it you need to completely refactor your controller code.

```
foodApp.controller('foodController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.handleFoodChange = function() {

        $scope.outcome = $scope.foods;
        if($scope.foods){
            var foodsArray = $scope.foods.split(',');

            if(foodsArray.length<=4)
                $scope.outcome = "Bon Appetit!";
            else if(foodsArray.length<=7)
                $scope.outcome = "Pig!";
            else
                $scope.outcome = "One at a time, your scale is going to shout!!";
        }
    }
});
```

and in your view you should change your input to this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foods" ng-change="handleFoodChange()" />
```

That should make your application work as expected. Now, whenever you make a change in the input field, the function `handleFoodChange` is called, and it handles the logic that sets a value for the `$scope.outcome` variable.

[Here's a Plunker showing it working](https://embed.plnkr.co/H8jZVN7Y6mLGAd3emJJs/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I understand the problem though. Am I supposed to attach $scope to everything in the controller, I can't create variables? I guess I don't get why my $scope.foods is undefined, shouldn't it just be an empty string, since there's nothing in the input box?

Comment: You can use variables just fine. $scope.foods is undefined because a controller is actually just a function - a constructor - that is called only once when the application bootstraps. That's before the user have had any chance to input anything. So your line `var foods = $scope.foods` (and the rest of your code) is called only that one time. That is why I create a callback function instead, so your code can be called on demand from your view. I suggest you find a good tutorial on angular, and follow it closely. Angular can have quite a steep learning curve and this is just the basics really.